# recursive nested private function

Tags: javascript, recursion

So maybe I'm making this too complicated, but what I want is a private function that I can call from public methods. The private function is recursive. I've gone through several iterations including trying to bind this in various contexts, but no go so far.

My input is something like this:

```
var row = new Row(["", "", ["AB", "AC"], "TR"]);
var badAbbrs = ["AC", "AD", "XX"];
row.badAbbreviations(badAbbrs);
```

And what I want out is: `["", "", "AC", ""]`

This is the relevant sections of my current try:

```
function Row(r) {
  this.data = r;

  this.check = function (coll) {
    function icheck (val) {
      if (val.length == 0) {
        return "";
      } else {
        if (_.isArray(val) ) {
          var out = _.compact(val.map(icheck) );
          return out.length == 0 ? "" : out;
        } else {
          return (coll.indexOf(val.replace("*",""))) > -1 ? val : ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Row.prototype.badAbbreviations = function (badAbbrs) {
  var fcheck = this.check(badAbbrs);
  return this.data.map(fcheck);
}
```

The error I'm getting is: TypeError: (class)@398632c0 is not a function, it is undefined. The error line is the 'return this.data.map(fcheck)' line.

Edit: for typos. the editor keeps changing fcheck to check.

Comment: `this.data.map(check)`? So where is `check` at? Why is the output `["", "", "AC", ""]`, could you explain more? You may have an XY problem here...

Comment: Did you mean `fcheck` instead of `check`? Also, `this.check` does not return a function, so you can't pass the return value to `.map()`.

Comment: You're very confused. Your `check` function does not do anything, because its internal `icheck` function is never called. It doesn't return anything, so `fcheck` is undefined. You're passing a non-existent function to `this.data.map`. Please fix these bugs, debug your code, and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: Yes. I meant this.data.map(fcheck)

Comment: I will admit to being confused -- fresh perspective helps to clear things up.

Comment: Why doesn't this.check return a function?

Comment: Thanks Felix! If I add return before function icheck (the inner function/closure) then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide a formal answer:

`this.check` does not return a function, it returns `undefined`. Hence you get that error message when executing

```
return this.data.map(fcheck);
```

since `fcheck` is not a function. Change `this.check` to **`return`** the function:

```
this.check = function(...) {
    return function icheck(...) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which method (class)@398632c0 is but i think the problem is:

```
var fcheck = this.check(badAbbrs);
```

I dont think you can link Row.check() with Row.prototype.badAbbreviations.check()

Why not move the badAbbreviations method inside the Row object function. I *think* that would fix the (class)@398632c0 (whatever that is) being undefined

Comment: Calling `this.check(badAbbrs);` should not be a problem. `check` is a property of the `row` object and `badAbbreviations` is called as `row.badAbbreviations()`, so `this` will refer to `row`. It's all good.

Comment: 'this' is this case is reffing Row.prototype.badAbbreviations, not the Row object

Comment: No, it's not. `this` **never** refers to the function itself, unless you **explicitly** call the function like that. E.g. you'd have to do `func.call(func)`, and that's a very odd way to call a function. I reduced the OP's example to the bare minimum to demonstrate that `check` is correctly called: http://jsfiddle.net/f1tvupx9/